# Can a person of a certain mass lift an object of a greater mass through a pulley?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I have a person and an object where the objects mass is greater than that of the person. Then the object is attached to one end of string passing over a fixed pulley and at the other end the person has to pull the string to lift the object. My question is can the person lift the object? According to me when the person pulls the string with the required amount of force he also gets pulled by the same force and since his mass is lesser than the objects he gets pulled by a force greater than his own weight so he should get lifted from ground

Answer (score 2):

[Mechanical advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_advantage) allows a small force applied to one end of pulley system to lift a large weight on the other end. The force that you apply does *not* have to be equal to the weight of what you are lifting - this is the whole point of using pulleys.

Comment: But in my question only one fixed pulley is used so there wouldn't be any mechanical advantage

Comment: @yyzr Then the mechanical advantage of the pulley is $1$ and, no, you cannot raise an object that weighs more than you do unless you attach yourself to the floor in some way. The best you could do is jerk the object off the ground briefly.

Comment: Thanks that helped

Answer (score 1):

Putting humans in the mix never elucidates fundamental physics principles, and your initial analysis seems sensible--but you're imagining pulling through the arms. It's just not intuitive.

Here, just consider the potential energy of a configuration. You have a person (or a rock), $m$, and another mass (or bigger rock), $M= \frac 3 2 m$.

Now supposed the pulley has a 2::1 ratio.

Everything is at $z_0, Z_0 =0$, so the initial energy is:

$$U_0/g = mz_0 + MZ_0 = 0$$

Now remove the ground, then energy as a function of the persons height is:

$$U(z)/g = m(2h) - Mh = 2mh - \frac 3 2 mh = \frac 1 2 mh $$

So $h$ wants to be negative, the person goes down and the big rock goes up.

If $ M > 2m$, the the person is pulled up, and if we put the ground back and he pulls: he's climbing the rope.